# Error in Apple's Swift documentation on forced unwrapping in if statements?

Tags: swift

My [iBook on "The Swift Programming Language"](https://itunes.apple.com/us/book/swift-programming-language/id881256329?mt=11) contains the following example of a feature describing forced unwrapping in `if` statements:

```
let possibleNumber = "123"
let convertedNumber = possibleNumber.toInt()

if convertedNumber {
    println("\(possibleNumber) has an integer value of \(convertedNumber!)")
} else {
    println("\(possibleNumber) could not be converted to an integer")
}
// prints "123 has an integer value of 123”
```

But this isn't working for me. Xcode (6.0.1) requires that I explicitly compare with `nil`  as in

```
if (convertedNumber != nil) {
    println("\(possibleNumber) has an integer value of \(convertedNumber!)")
} else {
    println("\(possibleNumber) could not be converted to an integer")
}
```

Is my iBook wrong?

Comment: Please file this bug with Radar (https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/) There is a special category just for documentation errors and Apple has hundreds of people who go through bug reports like this and update the documentation. But they rely on us finding the mistakes.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert: See the [answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26170897/656912). It appears this isn't a bug in the documentation; it's a bug in (or at least a shortcoming of) the way iBooks are (not) updated.

Comment: The reason why it's out of date doesn't really matter, it's still a bug that needs to be fixed. If you file a documentation bug it will get forwarded to the right people on the iBooks team.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it's wrong or, better, it's outdated. The behavior was changed on the release of 4/8/2014, and you can see the changelog [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/RevisionHistory.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH40-XID_1636). The relevant part:

> Optionals no longer implicitly evaluate to `true` when they have a value and false when they do not, to avoid confusion when working with optional `Bool` values. Instead, make an explicit check against nil with the `==` or `!=` operators to find out if an optional contains a value.

---

That being said, you can drop the parenthesis

```
if convertedNumber != nil {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Wow. I wonder why my iBook didn't update (deleting and re-downloading did the trick; but I shouldn't have had to do that, should I?). I wonder how many others are reading outdated documentation (thinking as I did, that it automatically updated!).

Comment: No I guess not, however even the version I linked is not the most updated (I'm sure there's one with some revisions from September, but I can't find it anymore)

Comment: Too bad. The Web is littered with [tutorials that have this wrong](https://www.bloc.io/tutorials/swiftris-build-your-first-ios-game-with-swift#!/chapters/680).

Comment: Yup. iBooks seems to have a real problem with updating to newer versions. I always have to delete and re-download the Swift book whenever there's a release. Much as it's nice to have a decent book on a new language from the get-go, iBooks doesn't seem to be the best distribution system.